# Regarding java heap memory and system RAM

Tags: java, memory-management

I am executing a python program from java using process builder. Created a shell script file which sets some environment variables then executes the python script.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeAutoML.sh);
```

The class which contains the above code chunk will be called from a Java scheduler (ScheduledExecutorService).

MY Linux Machine had around 30gb ram.

My Questions are:

1. The python script is for analytical purpose. It will create some huge data frames to process the data. Assuming the max data frame size is (1million x 100 ). **Can it use System RAM or JVM heap?**
2. If it uses system RAm then how can I see the RAM consumption?
3. As its dealing with huge data volumes can I get OUTomemory error in JVM?
   Information: This program is launched in the WLS server (2 nodes) with a load balancer.

Please suggest the best way to deal with such kind of use cases.

Thanks,
Vijay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. A program run with ProcessBuilder has its own virtual address space. It does not use the Java heap. Even if you called another Java program with ProcessBuilder, it would be a separate process with its own memory/heap.
2. Things like `top`/`atop`/ Windows taskmanager which show all your processes. Your python process should appear separately.
3. The answer for 1. should make it clear that the memory of the python process is separate from the JVM, so you will only get OutOfMemory for the Java process if you actually run out of physical (or rather virtual) memory. Which can of course happen if your python process uses it all up.

In general, for such huge data tasks, you want to carefully check if it is possible to process the data in smaller batches instead of all at once. For example, if you have operations on rows of data which don't need information / affect other rows, then you can load row by row, process each row, and write it to the result file before processing the next. That way you avoid loading all data at once.